# Tutorial for SiteCore Rocks with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sitecore, sitecore-rocks

is there any tutorials for SiteCore Rocks using Visual Studio ,

I have already search in Google for various articles and I could find a decent one,

can you guys suggest any links/articles?

Thanks

- I easily learn visually , so a video tutorial will be definitely helpful

Answer (score 8):

There's a YouTube playlist dedicated to SitecoreRocks: http://www.youtube.com/view_play_list?p=2B8CA35C742803E4

In addition, Sitecore CTO John West has written a number of blog posts on Sitecore Rocks:

- **SItecore Differentiating Factors: Sitecore Rocks** http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/07/Sitecore-Differentiating-Factors-Blog-Series-Sitecore-Rocks.aspx
- **Introduction to Sitecore Rocks:** http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/06/Introducing-Sitecore-Rocks.aspx
- **Major Components:** http://www.sitecore.net/en/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/06/Major-Components-of-Sitecore-Rocks.aspx
- **Sitecore Rocks Connections:** http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2011/06/Sitecore-Rocks-Connections.aspx
- **Query Analyzer Ingredients:** http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/09/Sitecore-Rocks-Query-Analyzer-Ingredients-for-the-Sitecore-ASPNET-CMS.aspx
- **Sitecore Query Cheatsheet:** http://www.sitecore.net/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2012/05/Sitecore-Query-Cheat-Sheet.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Another resource is the Sitecore Rocks wiki:

- http://vsplugins.sitecore.net

If you have access, there is a forum on SDN:

- http://sdn.sitecore.net/Forum/ShowForum.aspx?ForumID=36

Answer (score 0):

Here is a video from Morten Ljungberg's presentation at the 2012 Sitecore Symposium.

http://link.brightcove.com/services/player/bcpid1642619173001?bckey=AQ~~,AAABffgMgck~,AYno53hm3AQXk8lUBh_uD7C3bn8DwQJc&bctid=1969350715001

A few things have changed since the version he uses....but he shows some cool things with everyday usage of Rocks.